# How to convert from frequency domain to time domain in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, fft

I know this is basic for signal processing, but, I am not sure what is wrong about my approach. I have a signal that behaves as damped sine signal with a sampling frequency of 5076Hz and 15,000 number of samples. I found from the following website how to convert a signal from a time domain to frequency domain and managed to get the FFT and frequency values. The code can be found below the link:

[Machine Learning with Signal Processing Techniques](http://ataspinar.com/2018/04/04/machine-learning-with-signal-processing-techniques/)

```
def get_fft_values(y_values, T_s, N, f_s):
    f_values = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), N//2)
    fft_values_ = np.fft.rfft(y_values)
    fft_values = 2.0/N * np.abs(fft_values_[0:N//2])
    return f_values, fft_values
```

I managed to get the frequency and FFT values. However, I need to implement filters to remove some noise from the signal, so, I created the following functions to implement the filter part:

```
def butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, [low, high], btype='bandpass', output='ba')
    return b, a

def butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order):
    b, a = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
    y = filtfilt(b=b, a=a, x=data)
    # y = lfilter(b=b, a=a, x=data)
    return y
```

I know that I would need to implement the following steps:

- Convert to the frequency domain
- apply a bandpass filter to get rid of frequencies you don't care
  about
- convert back to the time domain by inverse Fourier transform

So, I created the following inverse transform function, but, I can't get the filtered signal back and the amplitudes don't almost match the original signal.
(For my case, I need to resample)

```
def get_ifft_values(fft_values, T, N, f_s):
    # Time axis:
    N = 9903
    S_T = 1 / S_F
    t_n = S_T * N  # seconds of sampling
    # Obtaining data in order to plot the graph:
    x_time = np.linspace(0, t_n, N)
    ifft_val = np.fft.irfft(fft_values, n=N)
    y_s, x_time = scipy.signal.resample(x=ifft_val, num=N, t=x_time)
    return x_time, y_s
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit 1:**

Based on the answer from @Han-Kwang Nienhuys. I edited the above code and applied it to the approach below:

```
##### Converting the signal into fft:
f_val, fft_val = get_fft_values(y_values=y, T=S_T, N=N, f_s=S_F)
# Applying bandpass filter:
fft_filt_val = butter_bandpass_filter(data=fft_val, lowcut=50, highcut=600, fs=S_F, order=2)
# Applying the inverse transform of the frequency domain:
x_time, y = get_ifft_values(fft_values=fft_filt_val, T=S_T, N=N, f_s=S_F)
```

Here are the results from the signal:

- FFT of the original signal:

[image: FFT of the original signal]

- Filtered FFT of the original signal:

[image: Filtered FFT from FFT values]

- Converted Signal from Filtered FFT:

[image: Converted Signal from Filtered FFT]

- Without Applying the bandpass filter:

[image: Without Applying the bandpass filter]

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the revised code, but the 'filtered FFT' does not look like you applied a Butterworth filter and the filtered time-domain signal looks like you're still taking the `abs()` of the complex-valued spectrum data. Start by verifying that the rfft/irfft roundtrip without filtering returns the original data, then test with a brickwall lowpass filter.

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys This is how I did my approach, see the end of the question

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys I did not apply the filter and the result can be found at the end of the question

Comment: Have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues:

- You are using `np.fft.fft`, which is a complex-valued discrete Fourier transform, containing frequencies up to twice the Nyqvist frequency. The frequencies above the Nyqvist frequency can be interpreted equivalently as negative frequencies. You are indeed using a frequency slice `[:N//2]`, but if you want the inverse transform to work, you also need to deal with the other half of the spectrum.
- Don't take the absolute values of the FFT data. The filter must operate on the complex-valued coefficients.
- If you use `scipy.signal.filtfilt`: that function operates on time-domain data, not on frequency-domain data.

For real-valued input data, it's much easier to use a real-valued FFT, which will behave more like you expect:

```
n = len(y)
yf = np.fft.rfft(y)
fstep = f_sampling / n
freqs = np.arange(len(yf)) * fstep
```

To transform back, use `np.fft.irfft`.

Comment: What if I was using scipy instead of numpy?

Comment: `scipy.fft.rfft` works the same, but has a few extra knobs to tweak the performance (and shoot yourself in the foot).

Comment: Well, I made the changes in the code, but still, I can't get it to work. See the edited question